# Prevent a [Run] entry being processed with Inno Setup installer command line

Tags: inno-setup

I am running an installer that I built with Inno Setup, and I want to be able to control whether the applications runs or not after installation. I am using the [RUN] section to control this, but according the Inno docs, command line parameters can only control the [TASKS] section. Is there a way to enable/disable items in the [RUN] section from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno doesn't have an option to do this built in, but you can read the command line parameters and make use of the results in a Check: function on the [Run] entry.
In code, you can use the `GetCmdTail`, `ParamCount` and `ParamStr`functions, or the `{param:}` constant (but it isn't as good for a boolean option)